# Choose Random Sprite Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I have 4 sprites, every time the game starts it would randomly choose 1 from the 4 sprites to be the main sprite.

How can I do this?

I know I would need to use `arc4random`

Comment: This question does not meet the standards of this platform. Please try to find a solution on your own first. If you get stuck post details about what you have tried so far.

Comment: If any of the below answers worked for you then could you please accept the same.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be -- First name you image (.png) files with some numbers for e.g. sprite1.png, sprite2.png ....

```
    int rndSprtNum = (arc4random() % 4) + 1;         
    CCSPrite *mainSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"sprite%d.png",rndSprtNum]];
    mainSprite.position = ccp(x,y);
    [self addChild:mainSprite];
```

This way you no need to take a mutable array etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are add all sprite in `NSMutableArray` as below code.

**Allocate Array**

```
NSMutableArray *AryT = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

**Differnt sprite**

```
CCSprite *torpedoOne1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"A@2x.png"];

CCSprite *torpedoOne2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"B@2x.png"];

CCSprite *torpedoOne3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"C@2x.png"];
```

**Add All This sprite in define Array**

```
[AryT addObject:torpedoOne1];

[AryT addObject:torpedoOne2];

[AryT addObject:torpedoOne3];
```

**Take Random number from array**

```
int RandomIndex = arc4random_uniform(AryT.count);
```

**Randomaly sprite**

```
[self addchild:[AryT objectAtIndesx:RandomIndex]];
```

Comment: Note that in this implementation you are loading the texture data for all the sprites. If the OP wants to use only one for a long session, this will result in a waste of memory. I'd recommend to only store the file **names** in the array, and when you choose one, you load the corresponding sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, in case you don't want to rename your files you can simply put their names in an array:

```
NSString *names[4] = {@"RedSprite.png", @"GreenSprite.png", @"YellowSprite.png", @"PurpleSprite.png"};

CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:names[arc4random_uniform(4)]];

[self addChild:sprite];
```